# Finding the centre of the ellipse $(X')^2 + 6(Z')^2 - 9Z' + 3 = 0$

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I am told that

$$(X')^2 + 6(Z')^2 - 9Z' + 3 = 0$$

is an ellipse, and now I'm trying to find the centre of this ellipse.

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%20%2B%206z%5E2%20-%209z%20%2B%203%20%3D%200) verifies that it is indeed an ellipse, but I'm struggling to see how it is. The general equation of an ellipse with center $(h, k)$ and major axis parallel to the $x$-axis is

$$\dfrac{(x - h)^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{(y - k)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

And the general equation of an ellipse with center $(h, k)$ and major axis parallel to the $y$-axis is

$$\dfrac{(x - h)^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{(y - k)^2}{a^2} = 1$$

However, the equation of the supposed ellipse does not resemble any of these, and nor am I able to manipulate it so that it does.

So how is $(X')^2 + 6(Z')^2 - 9Z' + 3 = 0$ an ellipse? And how do I find its centre?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Hint: $6z^2 - 9z + 3 = 6(z^2 - \frac32z) + 3 = 6(z-\frac34z)^2 + 3 - 6(\frac34)^2 = \frac{(z-\frac34)^2}{\frac16} - \frac38$

Comment: @achillehui Ahh, yes, completing the square. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(X')^2+6(Z')^2-9Z'+3=0$ is the same as $(X')^2+6\left(Z'-\frac34\right)^2-\frac{54}{16}+3=0$

or $(X')^2+6\left(Z'-\frac34\right)^2=\frac38$.

Comment: from there you should be able to see that it's an ellipse and what the center is

Comment: $$\begin{align} x^2 + [ 6z^2 - 9z + 3] &= x^2 + \left[6(z^2 - \dfrac{3}{2}z + \dfrac{1}{2} \right] \\ &= x^2 + \left[ 6 \left(z - \dfrac{3}{4} \right)^2 - \dfrac{6}{16} \right] = 0 \end{align}$$

Comment: $6(Z')^2-9Z'=6\left(\left(Z'\right)^2-\frac32Z'\right)=6\left(\left(Z'\right)^2-\frac32Z'+\frac9{16}\right)-6\times\frac9{16}=6\left(Z'-\frac34\right)^2-\frac{54}{16}$

Comment: But my solution is the same as yours, no? $-\dfrac{6}{16} = -\dfrac{54}{16} + 3$

Comment: yes, I think so

Comment: So the centre is $\left(0, \dfrac{3}{4} \right)$? Hmm, but what happens if we have $= \dfrac{3}{8}$ instead of $= 1$? Is that still an ellipse? If so, how does it change the ellipse?

Comment: It's still an ellipse; if you prefer, you could write $\dfrac{(X')^2}{\left(\sqrt{3/8}\right)^2}+\dfrac{(Z'-\frac34)^2}{(1/4)^2}=1$

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification! So the centre is $\left(0, \dfrac{3}{4} \right)$?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in just finding the coordinates of the center, then it's point where the gradient of the quadratic vanishes. The gradient is $(2x,12z-9)$. Thus,
$$2x=0\\12z-9=0 $$
and we see it's $(0,3/4)$.

Comment: Ahh, yes, that's a good way to think about it. Thanks!